# urllib2 request randomly stops working without code changes

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm querying the Mixpanel API pretty consistently, but every so often, the request does not go through and I am given this error:

`urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>`

I did some searching and there might be some caching issues, so I tried this in terminal:

`dscacheutil -flushcache`

I tried the above last night and it worked, but now when I am greeted with the same error and I try to flush the cache, I am still given the same error.

There haven't been any code changes that would have given me this error.

Any thoughts why this is happening?

P.S. Yes, I know urllib2 blows.  I would prefer to be using requests, but the urllib2 calls are in a mixpanel client and I'd prefer not to mess around with it.

Comment: Change your dns server, for example 8.8.8.8 is hosted by google and is rather fast with picking up changes, and generally hassle free.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Didn't seem to work unfortunately

Comment: Try after installing this pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1 
if you are using python2

Comment: What about saving the IP (if it's fixed, of course) in the local machine? In Linux you can just add it to /etc/hosts. Or you can run a local DNS (caching) server?

Comment: The solution seemed to be a combination of @ajay answer and the OS X Yosemite version of DNS flushing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be solved by a combination of Ajay's comment:

`Try after installing this pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1 if you are using python2`

and the OS X Yosemite version of DNS cache flushing:

`sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache`